# How to determine if results of two classification models are statistically significant without knowing individual predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

I have two classification models that I want to compare to see if one is "statistically" an improvement over the other. Both use the same training and test set and are only ran once for each model due to large amount of time required to train and test each model.

Is it possible to compare these models while only knowing the precision and recall for individual classes, and the overall accuracy?

Example Results:
Model A

```
                      precision    recall  f1-score   support

             Class 1  0.9464286 0.9423898 0.9444048      2812
             Class 2  0.9769179 0.9651241 0.9709852      1491
             Class 3  0.9560117 0.9541463 0.9550781      1025
             Class 4  0.8989726 0.9130435 0.9059534       575
             Class 5  0.9847870 0.9729459 0.9788306       998
             Class 6  0.9763033 0.9478528 0.9618677       652
             Class 7  0.9432076 0.9414966 0.9423513      2205
             Class 8  0.9591195 0.9452479 0.9521332       968
             Class 9  0.9197754 0.9332519 0.9264646      2457
            Class 10  0.9617225 0.9690083 0.9653516      1452
            Class 11  0.9613035 0.9421158 0.9516129       501
            Class 12  0.9368723 0.9610007 0.9487831      1359

            accuracy                      0.9487724     16495
           macro avg  0.9517852 0.9489686 0.9503181     16495
        weighted avg  0.9489823 0.9487724 0.9488337     16495
```

Model B

```
                      precision    recall  f1-score   support

             Class 1  0.9261626 0.9278094 0.9269853      2812
             Class 2  0.9719370 0.9523810 0.9620596      1491
             Class 3  0.9495050 0.9356098 0.9425061      1025
             Class 4  0.8929188 0.8991304 0.8960139       575
             Class 5  0.9815574 0.9599198 0.9706180       998
             Class 6  0.9524540 0.9524540 0.9524540       652
             Class 7  0.9342702 0.9346939 0.9344820      2205
             Class 8  0.9473684 0.9297521 0.9384776       968
             Class 9  0.9209454 0.9198209 0.9203828      2457
            Class 10  0.9574760 0.9614325 0.9594502      1452
            Class 11  0.9637827 0.9560878 0.9599198       501
            Class 12  0.9052265 0.9558499 0.9298497      1359

            accuracy                      0.9384056     16495
           macro avg  0.9419670 0.9404118 0.9410999     16495
        weighted avg  0.9387079 0.9384056 0.9384743     16495
```

---

Doing a small bit of algebra, I realize I'm able to work back to generate the True Positive, False Negative and False Positive values for each class. But this is where I am stuck.

Model A

```
  TP    FN    FP
2650   162   150
1439    52    34
 978    47    45
 525    50    59
 971    27    15
 618    34    15
2076   129   125
 915    53    39
2293   164   200
1407    45    56
 472    29    19
1306    53    88
```

Model B

```
  TP    FN    FP
2609   203   208
1420    71    41
 959    66    51
 517    58    62
 958    40    18
 621    31    31
2061   144   145
 900    68    50
2260   197   194
1396    56    62
 479    22    18
1299    60   136
```

Comment: How are the support values different, if the same training and test sets were used with both models?

Comment: Yes, I was confused by this too. I am using scikit-learn's classification report. Since all runs have the correct "total" (16495). I'm guessing this is the number of "guesses" for each category.

Comment: @MikeSmith Looks like I may have flipped the "true" and "predicted" value - I realize this would flip the "precision" and "recall" for each class, but f1 and accuracy should stay the same.

Comment: Support is the actual number of occurrences of the True value of a class label in the dataset.  I've never used that package, but this tells me the training/test sets weren't the same for both cases.  I'll wait for someone else to comment.  In order to compare the two models statistically, the sets need to have been the same, and the actual number of True values for each label needs to be known.  This will allow for an accurate weighting of the percentage for each class.

Comment: @MikeSmith You're absolutely right Mike. This was due to an error on my part. I fixed the example data to better reflects the question being asked.